# Django order by field comparison

Tags: django

I need to order_by a field comparison such that all fields matching a certain value are displayed at the top.

The SQL to do this is `SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY message='alsfkjsag' DESC`

Comment: What did you try?  What is your model?  What where the results from what you tried?  This is not "Write-my-code-for-me.com".

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do it:

1. Custom SQL with UNION:

   - combine two selects
   - one who contains all rows which have your desired message
   - the other with all rows who have another message
2. Add a dynmaic Field to the QuerySet

   - [extra](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.extra)(select={"is_message":"message='alsfkjsag'"})
   - and then [order_by](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.order_by)('is_message')
   - or in short:

   Messages.objects.extra(select={"is_message":"message='alsfkjsag'"})
   .order_by('is_message')